# How to avoid MongoDB Aggregation in a specific query?

Tags: mongodb, olap

I'm using MongoDB and need some analytics query to produce some report of my data. I know that MongoDB is not a good choice for OLAP applications but if I want to use MonogoDB one solution could be pre-computing the required data. For instance we can create new collections for the any specific OLAP query and just update that collection when some related events happen in system. Consider this scenario:

In my app I'm storing the *sales* information for some *vendors* in `sales` collection. Each document in sales consist of sale value, vendor ID and date. I want to report that withing a specified time period find those vendors that have sold the most. To avoid aggregations I've created a middle collection that stores the whole amount of sales for each vendor in each day. Then when I want to prepare that report I just find those documents in the middle collection that their dates is in the specified time period and then group the results by their vendor ID and then sort the it. I think this solution would have less aggregation time because the  documents in the middle collection are less than the original collection. Also it would be of *O(n)* time complexity.

I want to know is there any mechanism in MongoDB that makes it possible to avoid this aggregation too and make the query simpler?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid aggregations ?

Comment: Something like `db.middlecollection.find( { "date" : { 
    $lt: date1, 
    $gt: date2
  }   
}).sort( { "vendorID": 1, "date": 1 } )`

Comment: Because I think aggregations are very time-consuming especially when the data size grows beyond memory size.

Comment: @Veeram Thanks but I think it's kind of aggregation too because it needs to sort the data. What  I'm looking for is a pre-computing solution. Maybe with one more middle collection.

Comment: @Veeram thanks for your link https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb . I think since the time period is defined by user there is no way to make the query only a simple read but using document-Oriented approach would reduce time.

Comment: Coming up with the good schema design  with right index/ bucketing/granularity will help you build efficient queries.